# Ajax styled file upload & session

Tags: java, ajax, servlets, file-upload

there are two things which is important

1. send any file from client to server & save it somewhere in the server location
2. get the saved location of uploaded file and send back to client. e.g.
    `context name :    project

           predefined folder :  upload -> /project/upload

           response      :     /project/upload/file_exaple.jpg`

Ajax can't handle file upload so my idea is to send the file using form with `target` and save the file into server, also get the file path `/project/upload/file_exaple.jpg`. this part has been done & working.

```
form action="upload" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" target="IFrame">
```

once the first part succeed, in second part i can use `AJAX` to get the uploaded file location but the problem i am getting when multiple client's are uploading at same time. file upload succeed but file path couldn't find somehow.

I need to manage the file path with session and linked with `AJAX` somehow but i am not able to do that `[the second part]`. Any idea on it?

Answer (score 2):

I ran in too similar questions, i've found this ajax-uploader suited for all of my needs, might be helpful to you:
[Valums.com/ajax-upload](http://valums.com/ajax-upload/)